# Union of arbitrary collection belongs to union of two topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I consider J = J1 ∪ J2 where J1, J2 are topologies.

let, Aα ∈ J ∀α ∈ F

therefore, some Aα1 ∈ J1 & Aα2 ∈ J2 ∀α1 ∈ F1  &  ∀α2 ∈ F2

so ∪Aα1 ∈ J1 & ∪Aα2 ∈ J2 since J1, J2 are topologies.

therefore, ∪Aα = ∪Aα1∪Aα2 ∈ J1∪J2 = J

therefore, the arbitrary collection of sets belong to the topology

Is this proof okay?

Comment: You should use MathJax to format the mathematics in your question. See [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the union of two topologies need *not* be closed under unions:

e.g. $X=\{1,2,3\}, \mathcal{T}_1 = \{\emptyset, \{1\},X\}$ and $\mathcal{T}_2 = \{\emptyset, \{2\}, X\}$ are both topologies but $\mathcal{T}_1 \cup \mathcal{T}_2 = \{\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\},X\}$ is not closed under unions (consider the two singletons).

You can see where your "proof" breaks down.